# How can I render a view that is a part of my user controller on a static page like my home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm looking to place the signup form for an app I'm building on the app's home page, however I don't know how to render the view app/views/users/new.html.erb on my home page. Is there a method I can use to accomplish this? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a content_for block and then yield it on your application layout. Create a partial with your users/new page. (users/_new).

In your homepage.html.erb file add

```
 <% content_for :homepage do %>
  <%= render users/new %>
 <% end %>
```

Then in your application.html.erb file add

```
  <%= yield :homepage %>
```

Comment: did you successfully implement it?

Comment: Yes, the form is now on the home page!