# Rendering a partial with a new layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render a partial using an if statement and this renders alternate content. If I wanted to do this and render the content itself using a different layout (one without a header and footer for example), is this possible?

```
<%= render partial: "partialname", layout: "layouts/blank" %>
```

I've looked around and tried doing this in the view, but get an error which states

```
'Missing partial layouts/_blank'
```

Am I missing something? The layout isn't a partial, so unsure why it's using an underscore.

Am I better off doing this in the controller?

Comment: Try `layout: 'blank'`, perhaps?

Comment: I still get an error which points to looking at a _blank partial.

Comment: if there any action responsibke for that partial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I render a view that is a part of my user controller on a static page like my home page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334338/how-can-i-render-a-view-that-is-a-part-of-my-user-controller-on-a-static-page-li)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= render partial: "partialname", :layout => false %>
```